# KeyValueComparer based on key

Tags: c#, .net, generics, keyvaluepair

I have 2 key value comparers - in both I am using key to compare, which is string.
Can I use generic for the value - so instead of have 2 classes I can have only 1?

So instead of the classes below I wish I could have only 1 class

```
class KvpComparer : IEqualityComparer < KeyValuePair < string, T>>
{
...
}

class KvpComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<string, string>>>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<string, string>> x, KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<string, string>> y)
    {
        return x.Key.Equals(y.Key);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<string, string>> obj)
    {
        return obj.Key.GetHashCode();
    }
}

class KvpComparer2 : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<string, string> x, KeyValuePair<string, string> y)
    {
        return x.Key.Equals(y.Key);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<string, string> obj)
    {
        return obj.Key.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comparers differ only in the value type of the `KeyValuePair`, you could use a type parameter for the value type to generalize the two comparers into a single generic type as follows.

```
class KvpComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string,T>> where T : class
{
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<string,T> x, KeyValuePair<string,T> y)
    {
        return x.Key.Equals(y.Key);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<string, T> obj)
    {
        return obj.Key.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```